Playwright tests are failing on WebKit browser
I recently upgraded to Mac M3 Pro and it has MacOS Sonoma, I see all the WebKit browser Tests are failing with this error
com.microsoft.playwright.PlaywrightException: Error { message='Protocol error (Page.setForcedColors): 'Page.setForcedColors' was not found [{"code":-32601,"message":"'Page.setForcedColors' was not found"}] name='Error

I don't see any problem with the chrome browser.
